# onMounted triggers watchEffect twice

Tags: vuejs3, watch

I'm using vuejs 3 with the composition API.

One component with params looks like this: `https://webiste/accounts/1/4/2022`, where 1 = id, 4 = month.

In that component, I have 2 links to go to the next month or previous month:

```html
<router-link
  :to="{ name: 'comptes', params: {id: 1, month: nextmonth, year: nextyear } }"
  class="text-sky-600">next month</router-link>
```

`nexmonth` and `nextyear` are computed properties that go ... to the next month (and year if need be).

I run the `axios` call each time the route params change:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed, watchEffect } from "vue"

const getaccounts = async () => {
  // axios get results and put into ref ; cut for clarity
}
  
onMounted(() => {
  getaccounts()  
  watchEffect(() => getaccounts() )
});
```

Obviously, the first time the page is loaded, the getAccounts() method gets called twice. How can I change that?

Comment: Why don't you just use `watchEffect` for this purpose? comment the first line.

Comment: That's what I do. It's in the code I posted.

Comment: I mean remove the first line of `onMounted()` and just use the `watchEffect`